# How to change the Password for user over non-ssl LDAP connection in Windows server 2012 r2

Tags: active-directory, ldap, hashicorp-vault

when trying to change the password for user via vault for AD Ldap ( port 389), its throwing error:

"1 error occurred:\n\t* LDAP Result Code 53 "Unwilling To Perform":
0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A129B, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\n\n"

Server Details: Windows Server 2012 r2

Tried Resolution: [How to Disable "Password Operations Over LDAPS Only" policy in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861664/how-to-disable-password-operations-over-ldaps-only-policy-in-active-directory)
still failed to get the proper results

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the code/command with which you attempted to change a password?

Comment: curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request GET \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/ad/creds/my-application

Comment: Is that a custom web service that you wrote?

Comment: No, this is default command used by Hashicrop Vault to configure the Secret Engines, here in this case for AD

Comment: So does Hashicorp Vault use that curl command? Or is Hashicorp Vault hosted at  http://127.0.0.1:8200?